# home directory on desktop

Tags: directory, desktop-environments

Help I am pretty new to computers and I think I messed up real bad.

I was trying to organize my files putting them into different folders so I could have a better overview of everything. When i tried to move desktop I moved it into the wrong folder so I tried to move it out.

I couldn't and rapidly things went wrong to the point that when trying to access any application on my desktop it kept giving me error messages.

I tried alt print screen b restarting my computer and now all my folders are on my desktop and I don't know how to redo it.

Please help me my computer knowledge is about 0.

Update: I figured out i somehow deleted my desktop now my home and desktop are the same if i change either one of them it automatically changes the other i have reset my Ubuntu budgie settings but that didn't seem to have changed much either.

Comment: why don't you move your folders back?

Comment: Your post is difficult to read because you do  not use any punctuation. Please out of courtesy edit your post a little.

Comment: This is a long gibberish sentence, no punctuation or capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working from the terminal or from the graphical interface? It may be easier to get a grasp on the current situation and what needs done if you operate from the terminal, even if it is foreign. You should be able to open a terminal window by simply right clicking on your desktop and selecting it from the menu. Once you are there, you can confirm your current directory (folder) by typing `pwd` and hitting enter. This should show the path to your home directory, something like `/home/username/`.

From there, type an `ls` command to list the contents of your home directory. If there is no `Desktop` folder (note the capital `D`, as case matters in Linux), you can create one with `mkdir Desktop`. After doing so, you will want to confirm that the machine is configured to use this folder as your desktop directory. To do this, you will need to open and possibly edit the `user-dirs.dirs` file.

Before editing config files, it is normally prudent to create a backup. To do so, again from your home directory, you can execute `cp ./config/user-dirs.dirs ./config/user-dirs.dirs.old`. This will create a copy of the file with .old at the end, and in the event that this file is messed up, you can put the old version in place with the inverse of that command.

Then, to edit the file, confirm you are still in your home directory with the `pwd` command. Then, type `vi .config/user-dirs.dirs`. This will open the text editor vim and within it the config file `user-dirs.dirs`. You want to confirm that this line exists:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

If it does, then you are all set and can exit vim by typing `:q` and hitting enter. If it is set to something else, to edit in vim, you will need to first hit `a` (which will start the insert edit mode) and change the line to match above. After the change is in place, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit edit mode and type `:x`  then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the change. You will need to log out and back in for the change to take affect.

Comment: Thank you i created a file named Desktop but when i tried to make a copy of the ./config/user-dirs.dirs it said there is no such file or directory is it maybe named differently on my computer? I am running the latest version of Ubuntu lts if that makes any difference.